# File name too long error MySQL

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

using shell scripting to insert data to MySQL database, errors come out:

```
INSERT INTO $table (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k) VALUES ('','','','','','','','','','',''): file name too long
```

Comment: what is the columns data types length mentioned while creating the table. It only would have happen if the column in which your entering any value has max length less than the data you are entering.

Comment: This is not a MySQL error. It is coming from the shell. You probably need to quote the `$table` or fix some other shell syntax issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash script complains about file name too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959151/bash-script-complains-about-file-name-too-long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I think the problem is not exactly long file names, but long file paths, which is worse. limit is 99 characters.