# bash script complains about file name too long

Tags: json, bash

So I have a script that does this (jq is a command line JSON processor):

```
echo "Getting LB Node IDs"
echo $LB_STATUS | jq '.loadBalancer.nodes[] .id'
```

The output of the last line is:

```
1
2
3
```

But when I try and assign it to an array:

```
echo "Creating an Array"
nodeIdArray=($($LB_STATUS | jq '.loadBalancer.nodes[] .id'))
```

I get this error:

```
./myShellScript.sh: line 53: {"loadBalancer":{"name":"lbName","id":1,"protocol":"HTTP","port":80,"algorithm":"WEIGHTED_LEAST_CONNECTIONS","status":"ACTIVE","cluster":{"name":"ztm-n22.dfw1.lbaas.rackspace.net"},"nodes":[{"address":"1.2.3.4","id":1,"type":"PRIMARY","port":80,"status":"ONLINE","condition":"ENABLED","weight":1},{"address":"1.2.3.4","id":2,"type":"PRIMARY","port":80,"status":"ONLINE","condition":"ENABLED","weight":1},{"address":"1.2.3.4","id":3,"type":"PRIMARY","port":80,"status":"ONLINE","condition":"ENABLED","weight":1}],"timeout":30,"created":{"time":"2016-06-28T22:14:24Z"},"healthMonitor":{"type":"CONNECT","delay":10,"timeout":5,"attemptsBeforeDeactivation":2},"sslTermination":...<A BOAT LOAD MORE JSON I CUT OUT FOR BREVITY'S SAKE>: File name too long
```

SO $LB_STATUS | jq '.loadBalancer.nodes[] .id' produces a few numbers while trying to assign those numbers to an array doesn't work

Comment: `$LB_STATUS` runs the result of expanding that **as a command**, it doesn't pass it as data.

Comment: `$LB_STATUS | jq ...` is not an argument to `echo`; it is two commands `echo` and `jq` joined by a pipeline. Your assignment is just plain wrong.

Comment: You left out the `echo` command when assigning to the array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### What Went Wrong

`$variable | something` doesn't pass the text in `variable` as input to `something` -- instead, it runs the contents of `$variable` **as a command**. Presumably you wanted `echo "$variable" | something` instead (but see below!)

Even if that were fixed, the `array=( $(some-command) )` idiom is itself buggy. See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) describing why it shouldn't be used, and the various alternatives.

#### What To Do Instead

When feeding content from a variable as an input to a command, it's idiomatic to use a herestring: `somecommand <<<"$variable"`. These aren't free (as they create temporary files), but they're cheaper than pipelines (which fork off subshells).

If you have bash 4.x or newer, you have `readarray`:

```
readarray -t nodeIdArray < <(jq -r '.loadBalancer.nodes[].id' <<<"$LB_STATUS")
```

If you need compatibility with bash 3.x, `read -a` can do the job:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a nodeIdArray \
  < <(jq -r '.loadBalancer.nodes[].id' <<<"$LB_STATUS" && printf '\0')
```

...which also has the advantage of causing `read` to return a nonzero exit status if the `jq` command fails.

Comment: Assuming these are just simple numeric ids, I'd use `jq -rc '[.loadBalancer.nodes[].id] | map(tostring) | join(" ")'` to produce much friendlier input for `read -a`.

Comment: Your solution worked, and was simple. So did aalku's (though he's deleted his since). But thank-you. I don't know why I completely missed that it was echo in the previous line that was "pushing" it through the pipe to jq...feels like amateur hour here.

Answer (score 8):

You left out the `echo`.

Change

```
nodeIdArray=($($LB_STATUS | jq '.loadBalancer.nodes[] .id'))
```

to

```
nodeIdArray=($( echo $LB_STATUS | jq '.loadBalancer.nodes[] .id' ))
```

Comment: Reading through Charle's answer, I noticed that...seems so obvious now, not sure why I struggled with it so.

Comment: Yeah, he kinda went off on a tangent there.  He hates that method of assigning arrays.  I've been doing this stuff for over thirty years, and never had a problem with it.  Of course, that could be because I've been doing this stuff for over thirty years.

Comment: @Jack In this case it works because you "know" that the output of the command will be unchanged after pathname expansion; not everyone reading the answer will be as aware of the potential pitfalls, and may try to adapt the the code to situations where it *won't* work.

Comment: @Jack, I've only seen one case of massive dataloss in twenty years caused by shell scripts that weren't careful to avoid globbing when it wasn't expected to happen, but it was a doozy -- terrabytes of billing record backups deleted. It was probably the only time most of the other (long-experienced) staff saw that much damage caused by that small a bug too, but just once was enough to cost weeks of work trying to reconstruct old data. Just because one can *normally* get away with being sloppy doesn't mean one should.

Comment: @Jack, ...that aforementioned case was a place where someone "knew" that the contents of a variable could only possibly be a value that matched `[0-9a-f]{24}` -- until a separate program with a buggy library dumped garbage from memory into a buffer used for filenames, and something that "couldn't possibly" happen *did*. And these days, I'm working in security -- if someone assumes that a corner case "can't possibly" happen, someone else can work to figure out whether/how they can exploit that assumption.

Comment: Which is why some companies pay handsomely to hire people with 30+ years of experience, while others pay dearly for hiring people with little experience.